# Display count of distinct ID’s from multiple tables with HMT relationship in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I’m trying to display a count of all distinct Stadium’s a user have visited either via a Fixture-object(which includes a stadium_id column) or a Stadium-object.

I have a polymorphic table called Visit, to enable users to mark models as visited. This is currently used for a Fixture and a Stadium model via a HMT relationship.

```
class Visit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :visited, polymorphic: true
end     


class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :visits
  has_many :visited_stadiums, through: :visits, source: :visited, source_type: 'Stadium'
  has_many :visited_fixtures, through: :visits, source: :visited, source_type: 'Fixture'
end
```

The Fixture table have a **stadium_id** column.

In my User Controller I would like to get a count of all unique stadiums a User have visited either **by adding a fixture** or **by adding the Stadium itself** via the visit table.

Currently, I get all distinct Stadiums a User have visited by passing the stadium id to this helper method. But how can I also get all unique stadiums that the Users have visited via Fixtures?

```
module UsersHelper
def get_unique_stadiums_count(object)
object.pluck(:stadium_id).uniq.count
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
def show
   @visitedstadiums = current_user.visited_stadiums.distinct
   @visitedfixtures = current_user.visited_fixtures.distinct
end
end
```

**user/show.html.erb**

<%= get_unique_stadiums_count(@visitedfixtures) %>